# QuickSort C implementation not working as expected

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to implement the QuickSort algorithm in C, however it's giving me a pretty hard time, I don't know what I'm doing wrong but sometimes the output isn't what I expected it to be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printArray(int array[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int aux;
    aux = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = aux;
}

int partition(int array[], int l, int r, int size) {
    int pivot_index = (l + r) / 2;
    int pivot = array[pivot_index];
    while (l < r) {
        while (l < size && pivot >= array[l])
            l++;
        while (r >= 0 && pivot < array[r])
            r--;
        if (l < r)
            swap(&array[l], &array[r]);
    }
    swap(&array[pivot_index], &array[r]);
    return r;
}

void quickSort(int array[], int start, int end, int size) {
    int pivot;
    if (end > start) {
        pivot = partition(array, start, end, size);
        quickSort(array, start, pivot - 1, size);
        quickSort(array, pivot + 1, end, size);
    }
}

int main() {
    int array_test[] = { 948, 4, 0, 89, 7, 34, 1, 3 };
    printArray(array_test, (sizeof(array_test) / sizeof(array_test[0])));
    quickSort(array_test, 0,
              (sizeof(array_test) / sizeof(array_test[0])),
              (sizeof(array_test) / sizeof(array_test[0])));
    printArray(array_test, (sizeof(array_test) / sizeof(array_test[0])));
    return 0;
}
```

Input array/Output array:

> `948 4 0 89 7 34 1 3` -> `3 1 4 0 7 34 89 948`
>
> `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0` -> `0 1 2 4 3 5 6 7 8 9`
>
> `9 8 7 59 6 5 4 6 3 0 2 1 0` -> `0 0 1 2 3 5 4 6 6 9 7 8 59`
>
> `954 485 0 345 1 36` -> `954 36 0 1 345 485`

As you can see, some arrays are giving me some pretty weird results, and I don't really know why, so I'd appreciate if someone could help me figure it out.

Comment: since this is C, and not C++, removing that tag.

Comment: did you step through line by line with your debugger?

Comment: the immediately obvious error is that you pass 7 as the 'end' index, the last entry in a array of size 7 is number 6, ie length - 1

Comment: `-fsanitize=address` [finds](https://godbolt.org/z/ncv1xYa1d) a problem immediately

Comment: In your inner while loops in partition, l should not increment beyond r, and r should not decrement below l.

Comment: Oh, and remove that last swap, it’s invalid and not needed antway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- in `main()`, you pass an initial value for `r` that is too large: you should pass `(sizeof(array_test) / sizeof(array_test[0])) - 1`.
- computing the middle index with `int pivot_index = (l + r) / 2;` is incorrect: it may overflow on very large arrays. Use `int pivot_index = l + (r - l) / 2;`
- in the `partition()` function, the loop tests `l < size` and `r >= 0` are incorrect: you should instead compare `l` and `r` to the boundaries of the slice instead of those of the full array.
- the last statement `swap(&array[pivot_index], &array[r]);` is incorrect as the pivot may have moved.
- as a matter of fact, `r` might not be the final index of the pivot value, so the recursive calls should not omit this index. The classic trick to eliminate the pivot index involves swapping the pivot to the beginning or end of the slice and swapping it back to the final value of `r`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(const int array[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int aux;
    aux = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = aux;
}

int partition(int array[], int l, int r, int size) {
    int first = l;
    int last = r;
    int pivot_index = l + (r - l) / 2;
    int pivot = array[pivot_index];
    swap(&array[first], &array[pivot_index]);
    while (l < r) {
        while (l < last && pivot >= array[l])
            l++;
        while (r > first && pivot < array[r])
            r--;
        if (l < r)
            swap(&array[l], &array[r]);
    }
    swap(&array[first], &array[r]);
    return r;
}

void quickSort(int array[], int start, int end, int size) {
    if (start < end) {
        int pivot = partition(array, start, end, size);
        quickSort(array, start, pivot - 1, size);
        quickSort(array, pivot + 1, end, size);
    }
}

int main() {
    int array_test[] = { 948, 4, 0, 89, 7, 34, 1, 3 };
    int array_length = sizeof(array_test) / sizeof(array_test[0]);
    printArray(array_test, array_length);
    quickSort(array_test, 0, array_length - 1, array_length);
    printArray(array_test, array_length);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the last argument `size` is not used in the `partition()` function and not needed in the `quickSort` function. It would actually be less confusing to just pass the number of elements to both functions and adjust the array pointer upon recursion.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(const int array[], int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int aux = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = aux;
}

int partition(int array[], int length) {
    int l = 1;
    int r = length - 1;
    int pivot_index = length / 2;
    int pivot = array[pivot_index];
    swap(&array[0], &array[pivot_index]);
    for (;;) {
        while (l < length - 1 && pivot >= array[l])
            l++;
        while (r > 0 && pivot < array[r])
            r--;
        if (l < r)
            swap(&array[l], &array[r]);
        else
            break;
    }
    swap(&array[0], &array[r]);
    return r;
}

void quickSort(int array[], int length) {
    if (length > 1) {
        int pivot = partition(array, length);
        quickSort(array, pivot);
        quickSort(&array[pivot + 1], length - pivot - 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int array_test[] = { 948, 4, 0, 89, 7, 34, 1, 3 };
    int array_length = sizeof(array_test) / sizeof(array_test[0]);
    printArray(array_test, array_length);
    quickSort(array_test, array_length);
    printArray(array_test, array_length);
    return 0;
}
```

One last improvement: recursing on the smaller half limits the stack depth and avoids a **stack overflow** on pathological cases:

```
void quickSort(int array[], int length) {
    while (length > 1) {
        int pivot = partition(array, length);
        if (pivot < length - pivot) {
            quickSort(array, pivot);
            array += pivot + 1;
            length -= pivot + 1;
        } else {
            quickSort(&array[pivot + 1], length - pivot - 1);
            length = pivot;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great and in depth answer, thank you very much for your valuable feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Your main error is here

```
quickSort(array_test, 0, (sizeof(array_test) / sizeof(array_test[0])) , (sizeof(array_test) / sizeof(array_test[0])));
```

you are passing the same value for size and end. you need

```
quickSort(array_test, 0, (sizeof(array_test) / sizeof(array_test[0])) - 1 , (sizeof(array_test) / sizeof(array_test[0])));
```

Also when doing lots of index juggling like that you can do

```
int partition(int array[], int l, int r, int size) {
    assert(r > -1 && r < size);
    assert(l > -1 && l < size);
```

this will stop instantly in your debugger if you use an invalid index. This would have found your error

Comment: I forgot to add the -1, thank you very much, however, this doesn't really solve the issue, after making the change you suggested and testing with an array {948,4,0,89,7,34,1,3}, I get the following output:
948 4 0 89 7 34 1 3 
3 1 4 0 7 34 89 948

Comment: @VictorLopes put the asserts in, you will quickly find you error

Comment: Changing the pivot from the middle element to the first element worked with no additional changes, I don't really know why...

Comment: @VictorLopes not a good resolution, never be in the state 'my code works and I dont know why', this leads to 'bugs that go away by themselves come back by themselves'

Comment: Minor: since the valid index range is often expressed as  [0...size), IMO the more clear assertion is `assert(r >=  0 && r < size);`.  This also works should the index type change to `size_t`, unlike `r > -1`.